# Data on Recombination rate and Gene Positions in Humans

Tags: bioinformatics, human-genetics, database, recombination, data

I am looking for estimates of per base pair recombination rate in humans and indication on gene positions. The goal is to be a able to plot recombination rate in the y-axis and position (in bp) along all chromosomes in x-axis. Then add the genes on the graph.

I have never had to search for this kind of data. Can you give me some hints of where I could find these data into a simple format like the simple table presented below?

```
> Gene Positions
from       to
1145146    1147112
1568742    1570012
...

> Recombination rate
from   to       r
1      156787   1.2*1e-9
156788 256888   2*1e-8
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good baseline for this type of research in human genetics is [Standards and guidelines for the interpretation of sequence variants](https://www.acmg.net/docs/Standards_Guidelines_for_the_Interpretation_of_Sequence_Variants.pdf) from ACMG. It is a guideline for clinicians, and it gives a good sense of good variants data, bad variants data and setting up confidence level.

Try to consolidate data from:

### Population databases

1. GWAS databases

   - [Exome Aggregation Consortium](http://exac.broadinstitute.org/)
   - [1000 Genomes Project](http://www.1000genomes.org/data) (there is data in vcf format which is pretty much what you need)
2. SNV databases

   - [dbSNP](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp) (it is [uncurated](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3848/) so you got to be hypercritical)

### Disease databases

- [ClinVar](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/) (be aware "[12% of interpreted variants have ≥2 submitters in ClinVar , and 21% are interpreted differently](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/MedicalDevices/NewsEvents/WorkshopsConferences/UCM435464.pdf)")
- [OMIM](http://www.omim.org/)
- [HGMD](http://www.hgmd.org/) (it is a gold standard as it is curated, but you could only search for variants but not collect data because you could not download it unless you pay for it)